# Incorrect Syntax error SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, derived-table

What is wrong with this query? I keep getting an error

> Incorrect Syntax near )

Query

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) QUOTECOUNT 
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, DATEOFBIRTH, ZIPCODE  
     FROM 
         DBO.RATING_INFO 
     WHERE 
         STATE = 'Texas' 
         AND LOB = 'PersonalAuto'
         AND SOURCELASTMODIFIED BETWEEN '2018-05-02 00:00:00' AND '2018-07-03 00:00:00'
         AND REQUESTEDBYAPPLICATION = 'MR' 
         AND EXTERNALPOLICYSUBSOURCE = 'ezlynx');
```

Comment: Add an alias for subquery

Comment: I just need the count then why do I need an alias?

Comment: just unlucky syntax.

Comment: I added as whatever at the end no luck, this is where you wanted it

Comment: `SELECT  COUNT(*) QUOTECOUNT FROM (...) AS whatever;` is valid syntax.

Comment: Still I am getting incorrect syntax

Comment: @David Format your code properly.  No one is going to read that.

Comment: Or make it even simpler. Drop the subquery completely. It isn't needed. Just select count(*) from [The rest of your query here].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need the subquery alias, but I also gave the count an alias and put `State` in brackets for good measure. Should not matter on dbms, but I used SQL Server.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as QUOTECOUNT 
FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, DATEOFBIRTH, ZIPCODE  
        FROM DBO.RATING_INFO 
        WHERE [STATE] = 'Texas' and LOB = 'PersonalAuto'
                                and SOURCELASTMODIFIED BETWEEN '2018-05-02 00:00:00' AND '2018-07-03 00:00:00'
                                and REQUESTEDBYAPPLICATION = 'MR' 
                                and EXTERNALPOLICYSUBSOURCE = 'ezlynx'
    ) c
;
```

Comment: "*should not matter*" - `[STATE]` _would_ matter for other DBMS as that is invalid standard SQL ;)

Comment: I appreciate your feedback and the new knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative that isn't using a subquery. Since you want a count of distinct values you can easily use a group by. Add a little white space to make this legible and it might look something like this.

```
SELECT QUOTECOUNT = COUNT(*)
FROM DBO.RATING_INFO 
WHERE STATE = 'Texas' 
    and LOB = 'PersonalAuto'
    and SOURCELASTMODIFIED BETWEEN '2018-05-02 00:00:00' AND '2018-07-03 00:00:00'
    and REQUESTEDBYAPPLICATION = 'MR' 
    and EXTERNALPOLICYSUBSOURCE = 'ezlynx'
group by FIRSTNAME
    , LASTNAME
    , DATEOFBIRTH
    , ZIPCODE
```